# Нужна небольшая помощь с SQL запросом

Tags: mysqli, php

Приветствую.
Имеется простой sql запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pol`!='".$user['pol']."' AND `avatar`>'0' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

выводящий рандомно на страничке одного пользователя другого пола и с аватаркой.
Имеется такая табличка

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photo_raiting` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

в которую заносятся следующие данные: кто голосовал, за кого, какую оценку поставил и когда.
Так вот: вся проблема в том, что в первый `sql` запрос нужно добавить проверку, чтобы не отображался тот пользователь за которого уже голосовали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `users` t1
LEFT JOIN `photo_raiting` t2 ON t2.`id_user`=t1.`id`
WHERE t1.`pol`!='".$user['pol']."' AND t1.`avatar`>'0' AND t2.`user_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @vitagame, посмотрите примеры [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b7965/3). Там этот и еще один вариант.

Comment: Второй вариант вроде как работает. Спасибо. Но ещё потестирую.

Потестировал. Выводит мне людей моего же пола.